# Where and when is the local "holiday" celebrating Vercengetorix in France?

Tags: france, public-holidays

I am trying to find info on a sort of celebration in France around the gaulic leader Vercengetorix. I am not even sure what it is called. I know there is one because I initially heard of it through a websearch. Just looking for some proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct spelling seems to be [Vercingetorix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vercingetorix)

This story from NPR, [How Gaul-ing! Celebrating France's First Resistance Fighter](https://www.npr.org/2013/08/08/209514127/how-gaul-ing-celebrating-frances-first-resistance-fighter) states:

> The village of Alise-Sainte-Reine sits on a hilltop believed to be the
> former Gallic stronghold of Alesia, and each summer, it holds a
> festival celebrating Vercingetorix. Just as there is in the comic book
> Asterix and Obelix, there is music, drink and wild boar roasting on a
> spit.

This would seem to be the celebration that you are looking for.

Here is the official site of the museum [MuséoParc Alésia](https://www.alesia.com/lieux-de-visite-en/) in Alise-Sainte-Reine

This sub page lists the festivals [Les Estivales - du 8 juillet au 1er septembre](https://www.alesia.com/programmation/les-estivales-2023/) in 2023

And [La Guerre des Gaules](https://www.alesia.com/la-guerre-des-gaules/) may be what you are looking for.